# Github Pull Request API Differs from the web workflow

Tags: git, github

I am trying to use Github API to create pull request against an *upstream* repo

https://developer.github.com/v3/pulls/#create-a-pull-request

The API has the following parameters of interest.

head - The name of the branch where your changes are implemented. For cross-repository pull requests in the same network, namespace head with a user like this: username:branch.

base - The name of the branch you want the changes pulled into. This should be an existing branch on the current repository. You cannot submit a pull request to one repository that requests a merge to a base of another repository.

---

This model assumes that while using API, I will be the **upstream** repo that I can merge changes from a **fork:branch**

This is opposite of how I work when I use their web-app. I can submit a **Pull Request** from my fork to the the **upstream** repo, which is denoted as (base-fork, base).

It seems to me that without having an access to **upstream** repo, using API, I cannot create pull-request against it.  Can folks who have used github api confirm this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to have access to the upstream repository in order to submit a pull request against it, just like you don't need to have access to someone's email account when you send an email to them. Authenticate with your own credentials but post the request against the other user's repo.

> This is opposite of how I work when I use their web-app. I can submit
>   a Pull Request from my fork to the the upstream repo, which is denoted
>   as (base-fork, base).

I can't see how the API method is different from the web-app flow. When you submit a Pull Request via the web-app, the Pull Request is recorded and shown in the `base-fork` repo (to which you may not have access). *base-fork* in the web-app corresponds to the repository against which you will post a create-pull-request API request.

According to [the web-app documentation](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-pull-request/):

> When thinking about branches, remember that the *base branch* is
>   **where** changes should be applied, the *head branch* contains **what**
>   you would like to be applied.

This exactly matches the meaning of the *base* and *head* parameters of the API request.

Comment: Note the difference between `base-fork` and API `base` parameter. You will perhaps notice the problem.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran Agree, my reference to `base-fork` was inaccurate - I had the `base-fork`/`base` combination in mind. See the improved answer.

Comment: Sorry, the updated answer is wrong too. Look at my extract from API documentation. It says "base - The name of the branch you want the changes pulled into. This should be an existing branch on the current repository."

Comment: @SenthilKumaran And what's the problem with such a definition of `base`? Note that *current repository* refers to the repository against which the create-pull-request API request is being posted.

Comment: So, the branch in the "current-repository" means you need to have write/push access so that that repo.  This is totally different when you create a PR using Github workflow. You push to your repo/branch, and create a PR against the upstream base-repo, where you dont have the privileges.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran *You push to your repo/branch, and create a PR against the upstream base-repo, where you dont have the privileges.* The API implies absolutely the same flow - you push to your own repo/branch, then post a PR against the upstream base-repo, where you may not have the privileges to push.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran *So, the branch in the "current-repository" means you need to have write/push access to that repo.* And this claim is false. Posting a PR against a repository doesn't modify it in any way. If you clone any repository with pending pull-requests you will not find any of them in the repository. The pull request is registered on GitHub somewhere else. The owner of the repository will review the pull request and apply or reject it on their own. Therefore, no need for any privileges when posting a pull request against someone else's repo.

Comment: thank you for trying to be helpful. If you can, please post a snippet which uses the github api and try to create a pull request against this repo (https://github.com/orsenthil/fortune-chrome-extension) - Readme edit is fine. Make sure you use github api call.

Comment: @SenthilKumaran Run the following command and, when asked for password, enter **throwaway-github-account**: `curl -u throwaway-account -D- --data '{"title":"Proof", "base":"master", "head":"throwaway-account:master"}' https://api.github.com/repos/orsenthil/fortune-chrome-extension/pulls`

Comment: @SenthilKumaran For some reason I couldn't make it work through a token based authentication (I was getting a "No commits between *base* and *head*" error). But with a password-based authentication it works.

Comment: thank you for your patience with me. I verified that, it works.